# cx_Oracle. ImportError: DLL load failed: The specified module could not be found

Tags: python, cx-oracle

I get error when i'm trying to load cx_Oracle. But it never happens when i do it in REPL
however it's failing in standard Python evnviroment or PyCharm

thanks in advance.

Comment: Can you add the content of your links to your question, I for one am not willing to follow them.

Comment: If it works in REPL but not somewhere else, a common problem would be that the Oracle client libraries are not in the PATH being used by that something else.